# Make text follow a line and remain upright-ish for line directon in Omnigraffle

Tags: omnigraffle

In https://discourse.omnigroup.com/t/how-can-i-get-a-line-label-to-follow-the-line/32925 there's a neat "follow path" feature. That's great for lines that go straight down, or rightwards and downward. But what of lines that go leftwards and downwards?  The "follow path" directive for the text makes the text upside down.  I wish there was a follow-path with an additional "never upside down" feature, so I could move my boxes around at full speed without line legends causing me regret.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem for a specific line by doing the following:

1. Reverse the start and end points.
2. Remove the arrow from the end of the line.
3. Add an arrow to the beginning of the line.

That'll get you this to the chart on the right:

[image]

This isn't dynamic enough to freely move the chart around wherever you want, and if you're relying on the connection order, it's messing that up, but it will at least look right for a chart that won't change too much.